# Adding to the database without knowing ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have this

```
public class SchoolContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

lets say a student and a course has only a name and an ID... and a student has only one course and a course has only one student

now in my special controller method I want to add a student and a course at the same time, so I do this:

```
Student newStudent = new Student();
newStudent.Name = "banana";

db.Students.Add(newStudent);
db.SaveChanges();
```

But wait I want this student to be related to the new course, but I don't know the student ID because it is generated by the database, and I notice while debuggin that after adding the student to the database I can just get its ID using this

```
newStudent.ID
```

so I just add a course like this:

```
Course newCourse = new Course();
newCourse.Name = "platano";
Course.StudentID = newStudent.ID; //<-----newStudent.ID

db.Courses.Add(newCourse);
db.SaveChanges();
```

So my question, Is there any problem with this way of adding two things at the same time?

Is the student's course( its CourseID and its virtual Course variable) automatically related to the new course?

Comment: i dont see any probkems with that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid having to worry about the Id of the student by linking the entities.

```
Student newStudent = new Student();
newStudent.Name = "banana";
db.Students.Add(newStudent);

Course newCourse = new Course();
newCourse.Name = "platano";
newCourse.Student = newStudent;
db.Courses.Add(newCourse);

db.SaveChanges();
```

Also, you may have done it for a good reason, but it seems a bit weird to have a Student property on the Course class. It might make more sense to have a Course property on the Student class.

Answer (score 0):

That's completely fine but there are some things to mention.

First, if what you're doing is a unit of work then you should wrap it in a transaction - thanks to this all db operation that modify data succeed or all of them fail.

I would also change the Course class so that it will have reference (a property) to Student entity not just Student's id.